# Expanding only one node

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am using an expander that groups by category and want to expand only certain categories as default. That is, I want to expand some categories before the window is presented for the user. I have only found how to collapse/expand all categories by default.

Any suggestion to how this can be done?

EDIT:

Code snippet for xaml file:

```
<Expander IsExpanded="False">
 <Expander.Header>
  <DockPanel>
   <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
  </DockPanel> 
 </Expander.Header>
</Expander>
```

DockPanel is perhaps not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose to expand certain categories using the [Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded) event.
If this is your expander:

```
<Expander Loaded="OnLoad">
   <Expander.Header>
      <TextBlock Text="RightCategory" />
   </Expander.Header>
</Expander>
```

Use the `OnLoad` method to select the expander that you want to expand with, for example, [IsExpanded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.isexpanded) property and the [Header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol.header) used for the control:

```
void OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock tblock = (sender as Expander).Header as TextBlock;

    if (tblock.Text == "RightCategory")
        (sender as Expander).IsExpanded = true;
}
```

Infact, `Loaded` is usually the last event raised in an element initialization sequence. It will always be raised after `Initialized`; occurs when the element is laid out, rendered, and ready for interaction.

Comment: I am having problems. exp.Header is not a string and type-casting with ToString() returns "System.Windows.Controls.DockPanel". How do I get the actual name of the category? (Name is what I am grouping by)

Comment: The `Header` is an `Object`, its value depends on what kind of object you use as `Header`. If you use `String` you colud do the test as i wrote, if instead you use `DockPanel` you need to retrieve the name of the category from your object.

Comment: Big thanks for all the help so far! Using $exp.Header as DockPanel$ and $.Name$ only returns an empty string. I am new to wpf and xaml, so I am probably missing something obvious. I have included a code snippet in the text above.

Comment: `DockPanel` is not necessary, but it depends on what you have to do; anyway see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

[Assuming that you  have some data (in data context) upon which you decide whether to expand or collapse]

You can use a style for that:

```
<Expander ...>
    <Expander.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShouldExpand}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Expander.Style>
</Expander>
```